# Like not working in where clause in shopify-laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5.3, shopify

I am trying to make a search in shopify app using laravel but i cant getting result. when i use equal to operator it's working fine. but when i use LIKE operator it's cant fetch result from fetched array.

```
    $search_blog = $request->search_blog;
    $product_id = $request->HDNproductid;
    $shop = session('shop');
    $sh = App::make('ShopifyAPI');
    $app_settings = DB::table('appsettings')->where('id', 1)->first();
    $select_store = DB::table('usersettings')->where('store_name', $shop)->get();
    $sh = App::make('ShopifyAPI', ['API_KEY' => $app_settings->api_key, 'API_SECRET' => $app_settings->shared_secret, 'SHOP_DOMAIN' => $shop, 'ACCESS_TOKEN' => $select_store[0]->access_token]);
    $blog_info = $sh->call(['URL' => '/admin/blogs.json', 'METHOD' => 'GET']);
    $blogs_collection = collect($blog_info->blogs);
    //$blogs_collection_query = $blogs_collection->where('title', '=', $search_blog);
    $blogs_collection_query = $blogs_collection->where('title', 'LIKE', "%".$search_blog."%");

    dd($blogs_collection_query);
```

See above code , below result of $blog_info variable from shopify api

```
{#189 ▼  +"blogs": array:18 [▼
0 => {#190 ▼
  +"id": 119668754
  +"handle": "test9"
  +"title": "blog 2002"
  +"updated_at": "2018-01-01T05:05:41-05:00"
  +"commentable": "no"
  +"feedburner": null
  +"feedburner_location": null
  +"created_at": "2017-12-30T00:31:17-05:00"
  +"template_suffix": null
  +"tags": ""
}
1 => {#200 ▼
  +"id": 119635986
  +"handle": "test8"
  +"title": "blog 2003"
  +"updated_at": "2018-01-01T05:05:34-05:00"
  +"commentable": "no"
  +"feedburner": null
  +"feedburner_location": null
  +"created_at": "2017-12-30T00:30:57-05:00"
  +"template_suffix": null
  +"tags": ""
}
2 => {#201 ▶}
3 => {#202 ▶}
4 => {#203 ▶}
5 => {#204 ▶}
6 => {#205 ▶}
7 => {#206 ▶}
8 => {#207 ▶}
9 => {#208 ▶}
10 => {#209 ▶}
11 => {#210 ▶}
12 => {#211 ▶}
13 => {#212 ▶}
14 => {#213 ▶}
15 => {#214 ▶}
16 => {#215 ▶}
17 => {#216 ▶}  ]}
```

below is a result of $blogs_collection_query variable. when i use = operator it will be display a below result

```
Collection {#219 ▼  #items: array:1 [▼
17 => {#216 ▼
  +"id": 119865362
  +"handle": "vbxcvdsf"
  +"title": "blog2001"
  +"updated_at": "2018-01-03T06:01:44-05:00"
  +"commentable": "no"
  +"feedburner": ""
  +"feedburner_location": ""
  +"created_at": "2017-12-30T00:34:33-05:00"
  +"template_suffix": null
  +"tags": ""
}
```

]
}

when i use like operator i getting below result as a null array.

```
Collection {#219 ▼  #items: []}
```

how can i solve ?